# Energy-level choice for electron at photon emission

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, electrons, photoelectric-effect

An electron  absorb a photon and jumps to the last energy level.Now when it goes done,How does it choose which level it will step down to?.Also I've come to now that it can omit one step(e.g from 5th level to the 3rd level without going by the 4th) is that true and how come ?!.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do we really not know why atoms 'decide' to produce a photon?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/158604/)