# Newton's law of motion, pseudo force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, centrifugal-force, coriolis-effect

Can we feel [pseudo force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force) just like the real forces?

Comment: I think we can't because they are false forces and we can't feel a force which is not there?

Comment: But in circular motion it is written in books that when we move in a merry go round we feel a outward push due to centrifugal force, which is a pseudo force?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109500/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say in the comments, the so-called centrifugal force is a pseudo force, which we actually clearly feels.

But remember now, that a pseudo force isn't a real force. We *do* feel something during a circular motion, which indeed feels like a push/pull, and that feeling has then been called centrifugal force. But it is not a force. It is just your body trying to continue on a straight path, while the car tries to pull you along.

A pseudo force is not a force, but might be "felt" anyways.

Comment: I can explain the feeling of outward push without the centrifugal force. When we move in a merry go round we are acted upon by a centripetal force towards the center, this force acts due to friction, and it acts on our back, this as a result exerts a torque which tends to rotate us and we feel that we are pushed outward, then why we say because of centrifugal force we feel outward push

Comment: That you can explain it in other ways doesn't mean this explanation I gave is wrong