# Intuition of centrifugal force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, centrifugal-force, centripetal-force

I heard that [centrifugal force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_force) does not really exist; that it is made as opposite substance to [centripetal force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force). Is it true? Could someone define for me what centrifugal force is in terms of vectors and common sense?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force

Comment: possible duplicate of [Centrifugal force?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/108925/)

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109500/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8891/2451 and links therein.